# Bank balance query for UK visa from India

Tags: visas, uk, proof-of-funds

My wife and I have booked air tickets for London. Both of us work in a multi-national corporation.

How much bank balance will be considered as appropriate for our visas to not get rejected?

I am little worried reading about all the visa applications that are rejected. We will also have pay slips and company letters declaring when we are scheduled to get back to our office.

Itinerary: Bangalore -> London (stay for 4 nights) -> London to Paris (by Eurostar) -> Paris (stay for 4 nights) -> Fly to Bangalore.

All air tickets and train tickets are confirmed.

Comment: They care more about statements that show a consistent pattern of income and intelligent spending (eg not withdrawing the full paycheck, upwardly trending balance). Don't succumb to the urge to "park funds". I'm sure we have a question about this already....

Comment: Please refer: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab